# Why does this "Mysql" query hangs once a while?

Tags: mysql, sql, key-value, entity-attribute-value, sqlperformance

I'm working with complex `MySQL query` to fetch data over `Key,Value` table. IN order to achieve that we are doing multiply `self joins`. At the beginning we thought that the issue is `bit-wise` operations in `MySQL` as they cannot be done with `indexes`. **But** The issue still exists without using `bit-wise` operations. i.e the same happens if changing all `bit-wise OR` to `equal (==)`

### Query

The following `query` usually runs around 500 Milliseconds . But **once a while**  `MySQL` runs this query over **10 seconds!!** and even more..

```
SELECT DISTINCT sometable1_.id AS col_0_0_,
            sometable1_.hebrewName AS col_1_0_,
            sometable1_.urlBestBigPhoto AS col_2_0_
FROM sometable1 sometable1_
INNER JOIN sometable2 characters1_ ON sometable1_.id=characters1_.term_id
INNER JOIN sometable2 characters2_ ON sometable1_.id=characters2_.term_id
INNER JOIN sometable2 characters3_ ON sometable1_.id=characters3_.term_id
INNER JOIN sometable2 characters4_ ON sometable1_.id=characters4_.term_id
INNER JOIN sometable2 characters5_ ON sometable1_.id=characters5_.term_id
INNER JOIN sometable2 characters6_ ON sometable1_.id=characters6_.term_id
INNER JOIN sometable2 characters7_ ON sometable1_.id=characters7_.term_id
INNER JOIN sometable2 characters8_ ON sometable1_.id=characters8_.term_id
INNER JOIN sometable2 characters9_ ON sometable1_.id=characters9_.term_id
WHERE sometable1_.category="ABC"
AND (characters2_.value = 1<>0
   OR characters2_.value=0)
AND characters2_.name="somevalue2"
AND (characters3_.value & 2<>0
   OR characters3_.value=0)
AND characters3_.name="somevalue3"
AND (characters4_.value = 128<>0
   OR characters4_.value=0)
AND characters4_.name="somevalue4"
AND (characters5_.value = 1<>0
   OR characters5_.value=0)
AND characters5_.name="somevalue5"
AND (characters6_.value = 16392<>0
   OR characters6_.value=0)
AND characters6_.name="somevalue6"
AND (characters7_.value = 1<>0     OR characters7_.value=0)
AND characters7_.name="somevalue7"
AND (characters8_.value = 256<>0     OR characters8_.value=0)
AND characters8_.name="somevalue8"
AND (characters9_.value = 124<>0    OR characters9_.value=0)
AND characters9_.name="somevalue9"
AND (characters1_.name="somevalue10"  OR characters1_.name="somevalue11")
GROUP BY sometable1_.id,
     characters9_.term_id,
     characters8_.term_id,
     characters7_.term_id,
     characters6_.term_id,
     characters5_.term_id,
     characters4_.term_id,
     characters3_.term_id,
     characters2_.term_id
     ORDER BY sum(characters1_.value) DESC, sometable1_.text ASC LIMIT 10
```

### Mysql explain

After using explain we get

```
╔════╦═════════════╦═══════════════╦════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════╦═════════╦══════════════════════╦══════╦═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ id ║ select_type ║     table     ║  type  ║    possible_keys    ║   key   ║ key_len ║         ref          ║ rows ║                                Extra                                ║
╠════╬═════════════╬═══════════════╬════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬══════════════════════╬══════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ SIMPLE      ║ characters1_  ║ range  ║ FK_47,name          ║ name    ║      77 ║ NULL                 ║ 2146 ║ Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort ║
║  1 ║ SIMPLE      ║ sometable1    ║ eq_ref ║ PRIMARY,category,id ║ PRIMARY ║       8 ║ characters1_.item_id ║    1 ║ Using where                                                         ║
║  1 ║ SIMPLE      ║ characters5_  ║ ref    ║ FK_47,name,value    ║ FK_47   ║       9 ║ characters1_.item_id ║    9 ║ Using where; Distinct                                               ║
║  1 ║ SIMPLE      ║ characters7_  ║ ref    ║ FK_47,name,value    ║ FK_47   ║       9 ║ characters1_.item_id ║    9 ║ Using where; Distinct                                               ║
║  1 ║ SIMPLE      ║ characters2_  ║ ref    ║ FK_47,name,value    ║ FK_47   ║       9 ║ characters1_.item_id ║    9 ║ Using where; Distinct                                               ║
║  1 ║ SIMPLE      ║ characters3_  ║ ref    ║ FK_47,name,value    ║ FK_47   ║       9 ║ characters1_.item_id ║    9 ║ Using where; Distinct                                               ║
║  1 ║ SIMPLE      ║ characters9_  ║ ref    ║ FK_47,name,value    ║ FK_47   ║       9 ║ characters1_.item_id ║    9 ║ Using where; Distinct                                               ║
║  1 ║ SIMPLE      ║ characters8_  ║ ref    ║ FK_47,name,value    ║ FK_47   ║       9 ║ characters1_.item_id ║    9 ║ Using where; Distinct                                               ║
║  1 ║ SIMPLE      ║ characters6_  ║ ref    ║ FK_47,name,value    ║ FK_47   ║       9 ║ characters1_.item_id ║    9 ║ Using where; Distinct                                               ║
║  1 ║ SIMPLE      ║ characters4_  ║ ref    ║ FK_47,name,value    ║ FK_47   ║       9 ║ characters1_.item_id ║    9 ║ Using where; Distinct                                               ║
╚════╩═════════════╩═══════════════╩════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════╩═════════╩══════════════════════╩══════╩═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

### Some thoughts

I thought that this issue related to the `group by` and `sort by`. **But** same as in the `bit-wise` case, when `group by` and `sort by` is being removed from the query the run-time can still be above 6 seconds!

Any ideas what is the cause for the lame performances?

Thanks,
Oak

p.s

note: this cannot be `cache issue` as the first run can be very fast and only few runslater the query will perform very badly.

Comment: My guess is that it depends on the values going in and hence the number of rows being processed for the distinct and order by.

Comment: Could be waiting for an update query to finish.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your responses. It seems that is not related by values. `MySQL` can hang (more than a mintues) or run very fast on the same values. Moreover, an update on those table is not that common, so an update query is not the case

Comment: `characters4_.value = 128<>0` probably does not do what you expect!

Comment: MyISAM?  Or InnoDB?  What version of MySQL?

Comment: @RickJames, I wrote `=` and not `&` because i was tring to figure out if the issue was related to `bit operation` or not. I wrote above "But The issue still exists without using bit-wise operations. i.e the same happens if changing all bit-wise OR to equal (==)"

Comment: In MySQL's SQL, there is no `==`.  `a=b<>0` is treated as `(a=b)<>0`, which has the same result (barring NULLs) as `(a=b)`.  Ditto, when replacing `=` with `&` or `|`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it took a while to figure this out. It seems that because of some `duplicates` `keys` the query were real slow. i.e if one have table

```
id, key ,value
```

and the `key` cannot appear twice for the same `id`. then make sure you have unique  on `id,key` i.e

```
ALTER TABLE key_value_table ADD UNIQUE( key, id);
```

the advantage of this can be seen (and in time of course) `explain` query:
the `range` is no longer been used and now `MySQL` do `ref` for all  the `select` sentences

Comment: Typo?  Is "key" the same as "name"?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for `id` in the kv table; you do need `PRIMARY KEY(term_id, key)`.

InnoDB would be a bonus; then the key-values for each `term_id` would be 'clustered' together.

Comment: Interesting, can you supply more information about that?

Comment: The data an the PK are in the same BTree in InnoDB.  When searching for a particular `term_id` & `key`, drilling down the PK is the fastest way available.  At the bottom the tree is the desired `value`.  OTOH, with `PK(id)`, the `INDEX(term_id, key)` is a separate BTree.  First drill down it.  In the leaf node will be the PK (`id`); _the_ drill down the PK+data to find `value`.  'Twice' as much work.  (Wikipedia has a good discussion of BTree.)

Comment: Thanks, maybe you have some good information about `InnoDb` as well?

Comment: @oak - dozens of my answers on this forum address aspects of InnoDB.  And I have related blogs: [cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql), [composite indexes](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index1), [converting to InnoDB](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb).  Many of my other blogs give contextual reasons for InnoDB's behavior.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check into it